# Which is this formula Feynman talks about in the QED book?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-electrodynamics, path-integral

I am reading the [fantastic QED Feynman book](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QED%3a_The_Strange_Theory_of_Light_and_Matter). He talks in chapter 3 about a formula he considers too complicated to be written in the book. I would like to know which formula he talks about, although I have a vague idea. Please don't shy away from writing it properly, or giving a non-popular description or reference, I am conversant with basic QM, although not with the variational formulation nor QFT in general.

He talks about a formula for E(A to B), the amplitude for an electron to go from
 B to A in a space-time diagram), and states that it

> (...)*can be represented by a giant sum of
>   a lot of different ways an electron could go from point A to point B
>   in space-time. The electron could take a 'one-hop flight' going
>   directly from A to B; it could take a 'two-hop flight', stopping at an
>   intermediate point C; it could take a 'three-hop flight'* (...) *The
>   amplitude for each 'stop' is represented by* $n^2$ (...) *The formula
>   for E(A to B) is thus a series of therms* (...) *for all possible
>   intermediate points*

Additionally, I would like to know whether this book is another literal transcription of some lectures video footage, as it happens with, for instance, the 1964 Messenger Lectures at Cornell (published as *The Pleasure of Finding Things Out*). This is secondary and can be answered in a comment for instance, if you like it so.

Comment: A timely question - it is Feynman's birthday today! What better day to ask a question about his most celebrated work!

Comment: @innisfree, I didn't quite understand all the Feynmanmania, until I recently discovered that Messenger lectures... He is great. So deep, so pedagogic and, at the same time, so funny (he reminds me of Jack Lemmon in that lectures). Now I am reading this book and really enjoying it.

Comment: For a deeper (graduate / post-graduate) description of this matter (with Feynman's spark), look _Feynman, Hibbs: Quantum Mechanics and Path Integrals_ and _Feynman: Quantum Electrodynamics_. The first one will link things to the Schrödinger picture.

Comment: @firtree, thanks for the references! (the second one is the book I refer to in the question).

Comment: No, it is __not__. There are two books: _QED: The Strange Theory of Light and Matter_ is the popular lecture cycle, and _Quantum Electrodynamics_ is the graduate course. Please do not confuse them :-) And in a third sense, "Feynman's Quantum Electrodynamics" is one of the names for the Quantum Electrodynamics theory per se.

Comment: @firtree Ouch! Thanks for warning. So there is a "serious" version of the popular book I am reading now. I can't wait to put my hands on it. Thanks!

Comment: It is not even the version, it is a completely different book. Though on the same subject.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have the book with me right now, but from the passage you highlighted I gather that he's talking about his famous Feynman path integral formula. The partition function for a particle going from point A to B is given by 
\begin{align}
Z = \int_{A \to B} [\mathcal{D}x]~ e^{iS[x]},
\end{align}
where $\mathcal{D}x$ is the measure that sums up over all paths going from $A$ to $B$ (one hop, two hops, three hops), and $e^{iS[x]}$ is the weight of each path, $S[x]$ is the action functional $S = \int dt L $, where $L$ is the Lagrangian. From this partition function all desirable quantities can be obtained.

I'm not sure about your second question.

Comment: Is it straightforward to write $<B|A>$ in terms of that formula? That would make your answer perfect. I mean $<B|A> = ...$ (some expression involving that Z... sorry, I am also short on Statistical Mechanics for the moment)

Comment: I believe it is this thing I find in a book: $<B|e^{-iHt}|A> = Z$ but I am not sure. If you could confirm it (or better, add the formula to your answer) I would be very thankful.

Comment: $Z$ is a *generator of Green's functions*, which means that, with some work, you can extract amplitudes for interactions from it. $Z \propto <0,t=-\infty | 0, t=+\infty>$ - vacuum to vacuum. $Z$ is related to $<A,t=-\infty | B, t=+\infty>$ by the LSZ reduction formula, which is a little complicated. But the quickest way to calculate these things is with Feynman diagrams, that result from an expansion of the exponential in powers of the coupling constant. I think Zee or Ryder are good pedagogical, introductory QFT textbooks. The wiki articles don't look very nice.

Comment: @innisfree, you are right, Wikipedia is this time not as enlightening as usual. But your comment is extremely helpful, it puts me on the right track. You may try to write it as an answer in the other post (this one I should consider it as answered and give the green point to nervxxx, I think). You may feel it is not a complete answer, but as long as it is helpful (and it is) it is good enough. The book references are useful too (I have Zee's Nutshell, although I have not started seriously with it yet, I realized I need to study other stuff first, like Lagrangian Field Theory)

Comment: In general, the path integral is an integral over paths in phase space; i.e. there should be a $\mathcal Dp$ in you measure too (see for example Polchinski String Theory vol. 1 eq. A.1.12).

Comment: @joshphysics There are two slighly different versions. Lagrangian path integral, first invented, is over $\mathcal{D}x$, and the action is based on $L$. Hamiltonian path integral, most used in QFT, is over $\mathcal{D}x\mathcal{D}p$, and the action is based on $H$ (under Legendre transformation).

Comment: @firtree After having consulted both Peskin and Shroeder, and Polchinski just to make sure I'm not going crazy, it seems to me that the Lagrangian path integral is valid whenever the Hamiltonian depends quadratically on momentum.  In this case, the integral over $p$ is Gaussian and can be performed explicitly leaving only the $x$ integration.  You may be right however that even if the integral over $p$ can't be performed in practice, the Lagrangian path integral can be written down in principle and is equivalent to the Hamiltonian form.  I'm not sure on this point...

Comment: @joshphysics This is from _Prokhorov, Shabanov: Hamiltonian Mechanics of Gauge Systems_ (in Russian) (which seems to be more advanced than Peskin, Shroeder). It should be well-known in literature on English, too. Your guess about their relation is right. About your question, I don't know the answer.

Comment: @joshphysics There is no $\mathcal{D}p$ measure because I used the Lagrangian formalism, not the Hamiltonian formalism. Equivalently one can think of it as me already having done the $\mathcal{D}p$ integral to get the above path integral expression.

Comment: @joshphysics ah sorry I see that other people have already commented on that, didn't read those comments.